# Adjusting the pitch of an audio clip also adjusts the speed

Tags: audio

When I raise and lower the pitch of an audio clip it also increases/decreases the speed of the sound. I just want to adjust the pitch and not the length. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not in blender 2.93- . The pitch control is just a regular speed control. Also, the effect is time-relative to the beginning of the strip, so playing from the middle will not sound the same as playing from the beginning. That is a known limitation. However, you can use an external program such as [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org) to create such effects. With the FFmpeg library set up in Audacity’s preferences, you can even import audio straight from video files within Audacity.

Comment: Do you know if newer versions of blender can do this now?

Comment: @AMixOfGeekStuff I just tested it, and the speed control has been removed altogether. I still recommend Audacity, which has thankfully improved quite a bit since I posted the answer. However, you seem pretty specific in wanting this particular functionality in Blender itself. What are you wanting to use it for? Maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: Honestly just convenience. Itd be easier to only use blender instead of having to switch to audacity, with its different controls for zooming and panning, and then I have to export it to my PC and then find it on my PC and drag the file to blender.

Comment: You can bookmark the locations in both applications, you know.